# Laravel Raw query paginate; raw query to eloquent object

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4, eloquent

```
select '0000-00-00' as date, 'Opening Balance' as narration, (SELECT debit FROM `account_sub_journal` where id=1)as debit, (SELECT credit FROM `account_sub_journal` where id=1)as credit, '0' as transaction_entry_id,'0' as account_sub_journal_id  UNION SELECT * FROM `ledgertransactions` where account_sub_journal_id = 1 and `date` BETWEEN  '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-10'
```

I currently do this as a static function in model. I couldn't paginate this since laravel says it is not an object

```
public static function ledgerbook_to($account_id,$date){
        $book =  DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT  '0000-00-00' AS DATE,  'Opening Balance' AS narration, (SELECT debit FROM  `account_sub_journal` WHERE id =1) AS debit, (SELECT credit FROM  `account_sub_journal` WHERE id = :account_id) AS credit,  '0' AS transaction_entry_id,  '0' AS account_sub_journal_id UNION SELECT * FROM  `ledgertransactions` WHERE account_sub_journal_id =:account_id_t and `date` <= :date_to "), array(
   'account_id' => $account_id,'account_id_t' => $account_id,'date_to' => $date));
        return $book;
    }
```

I could union this if at least solve below query in eloquent.

```
SELECT  '0000-00-00' AS DATE,  'Opening Balance' AS narration, (SELECT debit FROM  `account_sub_journal` WHERE id =1) AS debit, (SELECT credit FROM  `account_sub_journal` WHERE id =1) AS credit,  '0' AS transaction_entry_id,  '0' AS account_sub_journal_id
```

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 3):

You can generate pagination links manually using something like this:

```
$pagination = Paginator::make($book, count($book), 5);
```

Then you may use something like this:

```
echo $pagination->links();
```

Or (`Blade`) this:

```
{{ $pagination->links() }}
```

Check [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage) to know more about creating pagination manually.

Comment: How? @Metra, you need to pass the `array` as `$books`.