# Raw relevance query in Laravel. How to handle it?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm currently transfering a big project to Laravel framework http://hobbyathletes.com/events/south-america/all-event-types/all/. I need to migrate my internal searchengine, which uses the following query (if searched for one word, here additional pre-selected option South America ):

```
SELECT *, (
 (CASE WHEN name LIKE '%searchthis%' THEN 1000 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN name LIKE 'searchthis %' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN name LIKE 'searchthis%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN name LIKE '% searchthis %' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN city LIKE '%searchthis%' THEN 500 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN city LIKE 'searchthis%' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN city LIKE 'searchthis %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN city LIKE '% searchthis %' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN country LIKE '%searchthis%' THEN 500 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN country LIKE 'searchthis%' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN country LIKE 'searchthis %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN country LIKE '% searchthis %' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN homepage LIKE '%searchthis%' THEN 600 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN headline LIKE '%searchthis%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN headline LIKE 'searchthis%' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN headline LIKE 'searchthis %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN headline LIKE '% searchthis %' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN description LIKE '%searchthis%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN description LIKE 'searchthis%' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN description LIKE 'searchthis %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN description LIKE '% searchthis %' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN distances LIKE '%searchthis%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN distances LIKE 'searchthis%' THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN distances LIKE 'searchthis %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN distances LIKE '% searchthis %' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN date LIKE '%2014%' THEN 300 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN name LIKE '%2014%' THEN 200 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN date LIKE '%2013%' THEN 200 ELSE 0 END) + 
 (CASE WHEN name LIKE '%2013%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) 
) 
 AS relevance 
 FROM events 
 WHERE 
 (
 country = 'Argentina' or 
 country = 'Bolivia' or 
 country = 'Brazil' or 
 country = 'Chile' or 
 country = 'Colombia' or 
 country = 'Ecuador' or 
 country = 'Guyana' or 
 country = 'Paraguay' or 
 country = 'Peru' or 
 country = 'Suriname' or 
 country = 'Uganda' or 
 country = 'Uruguay' or 
 country = 'Venezuela'
 ) 
 AND
 ( 
 name LIKE '%searchthis%' OR 
 country LIKE '%searchthis%' OR 
 city LIKE '%searchthis%' OR 
 homepage LIKE '%searchthis%' OR 
 headline LIKE '%searchthis%' OR 
 description LIKE '%searchthis%' OR 
 distances LIKE '%searchthis%'
) 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

How can I transfer this query to Eloquent Query builder? I tried already `DB:raw($query)` which seems not to work... Tried is with the much needed `->paginate(25)` and with `->get()`, all not working. Anyone here can put me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899354/laravel-raw-query-paginate-raw-query-to-eloquent-object

Comment: What type of error do you get?

Comment: I didn't get any error, but the article actually helped; I had to use DB::select(DB::raw($myQuery));

Then I had to build my own paginator, but that was easy enough, but not with the Paginate::make thingy, that didn't do it for me. I added a LIMIT to the query:

$limit = " LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$perpage).",".$perpage;

Comment: Yeesh. I'm guessing that query doesn't run very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try with DB::select()

```
DB::select(DB::raw("
    SELECT * FROM bla bla bla  
"));
```