# MySQL Use of IN, LIKE and OR

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am attempting to write a search algorithm, nothing too advanced but it isnt just WHERE `field1` = 'searchtext'. I am trying to search all keywords across multiple fields.

I have done a bit of searching and it seems as though my take on the matter is not compliant with MySQL's use of 'IN' with other functions, however I cannot find anything that seems to suggest a better way either here on stackoverflow or using google on independant blogs and other tutorial sites.

```
$fields = array('type','suburb','postcode','address');      // Fields in db being searched
$queried = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['keyword']);   // Input from form
$keys = explode(" ",$queried);                              // Determine individual keywords
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE ";                 // Beginning of SQL Statement

$frc = 0;    // Field Counter
foreach($fields as $f){
$inner = ''; // Reset $inner each run
$irc = 0;    // Reset Inner Counter each run
$frc++;      // Increase Field Counter
if($frc != 1){ $sql .= " OR "; }    // All except first runthrough
$sql .= "`".$f."` IN ";             // `field` IN
    foreach($keys as $k){
        $irc++;                     // Increase inner counter
        if($irc == 1){
            $inner .= "('%".$k."%'";    // First Inner per run (aka each keyword)
        }else{
            $inner .= ", '%".$k."%'";   // All other Inners
        }
    }
    $inner .= ")";  // Inner finishes run before reset
$sql .= $inner;     // Add Inner to SQL ready for query
}
$sql .= ";";        // Clean finish to SQL statement

$SearchProperties = $db->query($sql);   // Run Query
```

I have included commentary to help you understand my messy code and what I felt I was doing. The code is giving me the expected output, for example if I search the keyword "house" my output is as follows;

```
$queried = house 3064
$sql = SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE `type` IN ('%house%', '%3064%') OR `suburb` IN ('%house%', '%3064%') OR `postcode` IN ('%house%', '%3064%') OR `address` IN ('%house%', '%3064%');
```

Within the `type` column there is house and townhouse, it should be able to hit both, and should hit anything with the postcode 3064 regardless of if it has house in another column (According to what I want to accomplish)

However after several hours of searching, although my output is as desired I don't believe it to be correct. Could anybody help shed some light on the CORRECT method of solving my quandry and WHY this does not work? I always like to understand and learn from these sort of misunderstandings.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe my relevance query here will give you some ideas: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686084/raw-relevance-query-in-laravel-how-to-handle-it
It's also generated depending on the number of keywords and there are some preselections possible in the searchmask: Here is the live version of this query:
http://hobbyathletes.com/events/world-wide/all-event-types/all/?searchword=something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have wildcards, you want `like` rather than `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `properties`
WHERE (`type` LIKE '%house%') OR
      (`suburb` LIKE '%house%') OR
      (`postcode` LIKE '%house%') OR
      (`address` LIKE '%house%');
```

However, I would strongly suggest that you investigate full text indexes (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)).  The use of `MATCH()` may greatly simplify your efforts.

EDIT:

Your query is still incorrect.  And you should still be using `like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `properties`
WHERE (`type` LIKE '%house%' or type like '%3064%') OR
      (`suburb` LIKE '%house%' or suburb like '%3064%') OR
      (`postcode` LIKE '%house%' or postcode like '%3064%') OR
      (`address` LIKE '%house%' or address like '%3064%');
```

Comment: The problem here being that the textfield accepts multiple keywords and I want them all to resolve hits, much like google's algorithm. I dont necessarily feel the need to have only results that have BOTH (using AND) keywords within them. I would typically use your posted code, however it doesn't fit my need. I will look into indexes in the meantime.

Comment: @Tarquin . . . Your question appears to be about one keyword, and the code in the question shouldn't work.  This will at least fix the code specifically in your question.

Comment: I have revised my question to be more clear about my inquiry.

Comment: Thank you for revising, I was hoping to avoid that many queries in a single run, when I found IN I thought it would be a better way forward. With this method, 3 words would result in 12 LIKE's, would this not cause dramatic increased in query times? I am trying to be efficient with my code and learn the correct way instead of the easiest way. Thank you for your responses as well, I appreciate your help thus far.

Comment: Let me repeat my advice in the answer:  use a full text index.  1 like with wildcards requires a full table scan.  12 likes with wildcards require a full table scan.  There *is* a performance difference, but much of the difference is due to scanning the table, not the `like` itself.  A full text index is much more efficient -- if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try change 'IN' to 'LIKE'.
For example

```
$queried = house
$sql = SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE 
   `type` LIKE '%house%' 
OR `suburb` LIKE '%house%' 
OR `postcode` LIKE '%house%' 
OR `address` LIKE '%house%';
```

If you have a several keywords, then you need change query.
For example

```
$queried = house 3064
$sql = SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE 
   (`type` LIKE '%house%' AND `type` LIKE '%3064%') 
OR (`suburb` LIKE '%house%' AND `suburb` LIKE '%3064%') 
OR (`postcode` LIKE '%house%' AND `postcode` LIKE '%3064%') 
OR (`address` LIKE '%house%' AND `address` LIKE '%3064%');
```

Comment: Regretfully you replied prior to my edit, while I explained I wanted multiple keywords I did not post an example, as such I updated my question to include a more relevant example.

Comment: I changed example for you